Angular - How to position a fixed navbar correctly when scrolling to sections with the same ID
I'm working on an Angular project where I have multiple sections on a page, each with a unique ID. I also have a fixed-position navbar that allows users to navigate to these sections. My goal is to ensure that when a user clicks on a menu item (e.g., Section2), the navbar aligns correctly as shown in the image below.

To illustrate the issue, I've created a StackBlitz demo. However, I had to comment out the following line <!-- <app-nav></app-nav> --> in the StackBlitz demo to make it compile:
Stackblitz Demo
I couldn't fix the compilation error, but that's not my main concern. My primary issue is how to correctly position the navbar so that it behaves as expected when scrolling to different sections.
app.routes.ts
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'section-1', component: Section1Component },
  { path: 'section-2', component: Section2Component },
  { path: 'section-3', component: Section3Component },
  { path: 'section-4', component: Section4Component },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' },
];

main.ts
<div class="container">
  <!-- <app-nav></app-nav> -->
  <app-section1></app-section1>
  <app-section2></app-section2>
  <app-section3></app-section3>
  <app-section4></app-section4>
</div>

nav.component.ts
export class NavComponent {
  constructor(private viewportScroller: ViewportScroller) {}

  public scrollToSection(sectionId: string): void {
    this.viewportScroller.scrollToAnchor(sectionId);
  }
}


Hi, how about the last element: section-4? I don't think that it's possible to pin section-4 on top after nav bar as when scrolling, it will reach to the end of the page and there is no space after section-4.

Also, one thing to clarify: based on your code you are attempting to scroll to the selected section, but in your screenshot, you are trying to add the navbar before the selected section. If I understand correctly, what you want to achieve is to pin the selected section after navbar?

@YongShun you're right, pinning section-4 after the navbar would be tricky because of the limited space at the end of the page. It seems like it might not be feasible in this case.
Yes, exactly. The bottom of the navbar should stay aligned with the start of the section.

Probably this demo should meet your requirement. It depends on the height of the page, so when it reaches the end of the page, then the section is not able to stay aligned with navbar. Let me know if this is what you are looking for. Thanks.

YongShun that's what I need.

As mentioned in the comment, you should scroll by calculating the position to place the selected section after the navbar instead of scrolling to the element by ID.
Note that, this approach has a limitation when the scroll reaches the end of the page, the section is unable to pin after the navbar such as <app-section-3> and <app-section-4> (You can see the StackBlitz link and open the Preview in the new tab for full screen).
public scrollToSection(sectionId: string): void {
  const element = document.getElementById(sectionId)!;
  const navElement = document.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0]!;

  const navHeight = navElement.offsetHeight;

  const targetPosition = element.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY;

  this.viewportScroller.scrollToPosition([0, targetPosition - navHeight]);    
}

Alternatively, you may look for scrollTo which has the same functionality and includes the scroll animation.
window.scrollTo({
 left: 0,
 top: targetPosition - navHeight,
 behavior: 'smooth'
});

Demo @ StackBlitz

try adding the nav at the end outside of the container so it will look like this:
<div class="container">
    <app-section1></app-section1>
    <app-section2></app-section2>
    <app-section3></app-section3>
    <app-section4></app-section4>
</div>
<app-nav></app-nav>

